# Extending folder with metadata, how to set up the "new" button?

Tags: content-type, folder

I want to extend the Folder content type to add some metadata. I don't want to use DocSet because DocSets cannot be nested.

Here is how I defined my content type :

```
  <!-- Parent ContentType: Folder (0x0120) -->
  <ContentType ID="0x01200068DA4365FBA041B0AFCD70DC516468F3"
               Name="Rubrique de document"
               Group="My group"
               Description="Dossier enrichi de métadonnées"
               Inherits="TRUE"
               Version="0">
    <FieldRefs>
      <FieldRef ID="{136FC864-53CC-4DFE-86EF-09F4036F4653}" DisplayName="Thématique" Required="FALSE" Name="OneTaxonomyField" />
      <FieldRef ID="{F50C8533-EF43-4A41-BD90-9845D3A37DAA}" DisplayName="Thématique" Required="FALSE" Name="OneTaxonomyField_0" Hidden="TRUE" />
      <FieldRef ID="{86139A10-CD97-4051-9CD4-B1D169E47067}"
                DisplayName="Masquer dans les blocs d'arborescence"
                Required="FALSE"
                Name="DocumentMasque" />
      <FieldRef ID="{C0CAAA38-268D-4B76-9730-B1B2677146E4}"
                Name="ElementContentTypeImage"
                DisplayName="Image"/>
      <FieldRef ID="{7662cd2c-f069-4dba-9e35-082cf976e170}"
                Name="Body"
                DisplayName="Commentaires" />

    </FieldRefs>
  </ContentType>
```

Then, I attach this content type on the OOB document library, usign a content type binding :

```
 <ContentTypeBinding ContentTypeId="0x01200068DA4365FBA041B0AFCD70DC516468F3"
                     ListUrl="Documents"/>
```

When the feature activates, the content type seems to be correctly bounded:

[image: new button]

However, when I click on this button, I land on the **upload.aspx** screen :
[image: upload url]

[image: Upload form]

When I click **Save** (enregistrer in french), **nothing** happens.

No error. No error in javascript console, no error in ULS logs. 
The Save buttons just grays out, and that's all.

**What is the proper way to attach my extended folder content type?**

I'm a bit confused by the fact I'm landing on the "upload.aspx" page...

**Edit** A bit of progress... if I remove the `Image` field, I can save the form correctly

Answer (score 0):

we recently faced the same issue and it seems to be a problem with publishing fields included into custom content type. Try to remove Image field from content type (which is probably publishing link field or publishing image field) and try to deploy again. This should now save.

To bypass this problem we have used document sets instead which allow to add such controls.

Hope this helps,

Andrew